# Library for database (schema) management

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, postgresql

I am looking for a .Net library which would act like an abstraction layer between the application and the database. The application mostly deals with structure alterations, like creating a new table or adding a column to existing table.

I would like to have the library which deals directly with database entities like tables, schemas or columns - so not really ORM (unless some ORMs have good "utility" layer). Support for PostgreSQL and SQL Server is required (Oracle and SQLite would be "a nice to have" feature).

Any free or commercial (but royalty-free i.e. no per-server license) solutions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the DAL, I recommend **NHibernate** (http://nhibernate.info/)
It is a great all-rounder:

- easy to use
- good abstraction
- powerful features.

It gets even better with **FluentNhibernate** (http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/)

--

If you are looking for something more speedy and light-weight, take a look at StackOverflow's very own **Dapper** (https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net)